# React+Typescript, About namespace

Tags: reactjs, typescript, namespaces, react-typescript, typescript-namespace

I defined the class `Header` in the `header.tsx` file and put it in the `BizComponent` namespace.

The `footer.tsx` file defines the class `Footer` and is also placed in this namespace.

How do I import this namespace so that it contains both classes?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

---

UPDATE:

`header.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
export namespace BizComponent {
  export class Header extends React.Component {
    render(): React.ReactNode {
      return (<nav className='header-nav'>
        <a className='left' href='/'>
          <img className='header-logo' src='/logo.png' aria-label='logo' />
        </a>
        <div className='right'>
          <a href='/article'>Article</a>
          <a href='/about'>About</a>
        </div>
      </nav>);
    }
  }
}
export default BizComponent.Header;
```

`footer.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
namespace BizComponent {
  export class Footer extends React.Component {
    render(): React.ReactNode {
      return (<div>
        <p className='footer'>
          Copyright &copy; 2022 (example). All rights reserved.
        </p>
      </div>);
    }
  }
}
export default BizComponent.Footer;
```

then import them...

```js
import { BizComponent } from './header.tsx';
// ERROR: TS 2300
// import { BizComponent } from './footer.tsx';
```

I'm looking for a way to replace this bad design...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import them separately using their relative file paths.

One way to accomplish something similar is given in [Importing a directory in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142486/importing-a-directory-in-react)

Comment: So how do I merge these two imports?

Comment: If I'm understanding your original question correctly, you don't merge them. You just have two imports.  React is designed as 1 import per file. If you create a file that combines imports like the one I linked, that's the closest you can do I believe. Please clarify your original question if I'm missing something.

Comment: I get it now, thank you.